# Serialize QAbstractListModel for networking (Qt-Server - QML-Client)

Tags: c++, json, qt, serialization

I'm currently writing an QML-app that uses multiple models, Objects and properties provided by C++. What I wanna do, is to centralize the data creation, to access it with multiple clients. Therefore I have to split my application.

**Server:** It should provide Models and properties whenever the client requests it.

**Client:** Requests data (model, object or property) by tcp.

I figured out, that JSON might be a good option to do so, since it works with plain text.

Is there a good (easy) way to serialize a complete model using JSON?
or
Is do you know another way to serialize complete models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every model has its own structure, data types (text, font, images...) and data processing mechanisms. That is why there can't be any universal way to serialize a model.

Furthermore, a good way to use model is to [treat it as an adapter](https://qt-project.org/doc/note_revisions/13/28/view). It is another reason why there is no any model serializer.

Thus you need to code serializing of data:

- You can use JSON. Look for a good parser for C++ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245973/whats-the-best-c-json-parser).  Or use [JSON classes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/json.html) if you use Qt5.
- Also you may want to look at `QSettings` which can save/read data to ini-file.
- Most of standard types have operators to be written to a `stream`. Then you can encode and transfer it via `TCP`.

Comment: @Ezee Thanks. JSON seems to be the right way. My application is already using models as adapter. There's only one thing I don't understand. Do I have to implement write and read functions for every attribut or can I pass a complete QObject to JSON?

Comment: @Quperman It depends on what do you call `attribute`. If it is a member variable, you need to write/read it. If it is a Qt property you can optimize it by reading/writing all properties in a cycle with `metaObject` info.

Comment: @Ezee Thank you really much! That solves my problem (especially the QProperty way).